# Marklogic json:config generate "_children"

Tags: marklogic

I don't understand why Marklogic json:config generates "_children".  How can I exclude "_children". I see all the enumerated children come back for parents, but there's a lot of extra junk in the JSON output.

```
let $config := json:config("custom")
let $_ := map:put( $config, "full-element-names",xs:QName("Nav:keynavlist")
```

Json output:

```
"Navigators": {
  "keynavlist": {
  "_children": [
     {
      "keynav": {
          "_value": "Fuel Cells"
      }
    }, 
 {
    "keynav": {
        "_value": "Microorganisms"
}
}, 
{
  "keynav": {
 "_value": "Waste Treatment"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you would like to get something like:

```
{
    "Navigators": {
        "keynavlist": [{
            "keynav": "Fuel Cells"
        }, {
            "keynav": "Microorganisms"
        }, {
            "keynav": "Waste Treatment"
        }]
    }
}
```

But closest you can get with the json transform lib is this:

```
{
    "Navigators": {
        "keynavlist": {
            "keynav": ["Fuel Cells", "Microorganisms", "Waste Treatment"]
        }
    }
}
```

Using:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

let $config := json:config("custom")
let $_ := map:put($config, "array-element-names", ("keynav"))
return json:transform-to-json(
  <Navigators>
    <keynavlist>
      <keynav>Fuel Cells</keynav>
      <keynav>Microorganisms</keynav>
      <keynav>Waste Treatment</keynav>
    </keynavlist>
  </Navigators>,
  $config
)
```

Consider building json with a recursive function, maybe something like this:

```
declare function local:xml-to-json($nodes) {
  for $node in $nodes
  return typeswitch ($node)
    case element() return
      if ($node/attribute() or ($node/element() and $node/text())) then
        object-node {
          local-name($node): object-node {
            "@": array-node{ local:xml-to-json($node/attribute()) },
            "_": array-node { local:xml-to-json($node/node()) }
          }
        }
      else
        object-node {
          local-name($node): array-node{ local:xml-to-json($node/node()) }
        }
    case attribute() return
      object-node {
        local-name($node): data($node)
      }
    default return $node
};

local:xml-to-json(
  <Navigators>
    <keynavlist>
      <keynav>Fuel Cells</keynav>
      <keynav>Microorganisms</keynav>
      <keynav>Waste Treatment</keynav>
    </keynavlist>
  </Navigators>
)
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question

> "I don't understand why Marklogic json:config generates "_children"

The 'custom' configuration is designed to support *bi directional* JSON <> XML transformations as much as reasonable.  THe "extra junk" you refer to (such as _children) is needed in order to reverse the process and generate the original XML.
The 'basic' strategy is for simple conversion one-way from JSON to XML, and the full strategy is for the reverse (xml to JSON) -- *while preserving as much information as possible*.

Since you are translating from XML to JSON, in which any xml element may have both attributes and child elements,  AND the child elements may have duplicate names, they cannot be converted to a simple JSON object without data loss (in the general case).

The 'custom' strategy has a great deal of flexibility (aka 'complexity') to address that fact that 'My Case' is rarely 'The General Case'  nor "Your Case".

One such configuration option is the abiltiy to specify xml qnames which should be converted to arrays instead of "_children" 
"array-element-names"

See the last example on this page:  https://docs.marklogic.com/json:config

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
    at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

declare variable $doc :=   <a><b attr="d">c</b></a>;

let $c := json:config("custom") ,
    $_ := map:put( $c, "array-element-names", (xs:QName("a"),xs:QName("b")) ),
    $_ := map:put( $c, "attribute-names", ("attr" ) ), 
    $_ := map:put( $c, "text-value", "LABEL" ),
    $j := json:transform-to-json($doc ,$c ),
    $x := json:transform-from-json($j,$c) 
return ($j, $x)

(: The JSON property name "LABEL" is used to hold the text value from
    the element <b/>. Without the "text-value" option, the property name
    would be "_value". The query produces the following output: 

{"a":[{"b":[{"attr":"d", "LABEL":"c"}]}]}
<a><b attr="d">c</b></a> :)
```

At some point -- the amount of 'configuration' needed to achive ones specific case-by-case transformation becomes more complicated to do as strategy configuations and less complicated to do as native xquery code ,  as grtjn shows,  this is a recommended solution for when it becomes too tedious or non-obvious how to 'tweek' the configurations to customize for a given use case.

I find a combination of pre-processing, json:transform  and post-processing works best for me.  YMMV

Comment: Thank you all for explaining.  I will implement code you recommended.